# Adding Image/Button Click Event Handler Dynamically in C# Silverlight

Tags: c#

Please check the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method returns a custom column control for the AgDataGrid from devex with a   button design including button click event handlers
/// </summary>
/// <param name="headerContent">The header column value for this cell</param>
/// <param name="control">The DataTemplate XAML needed to Load the control</param>
/// <param name="routedEventHandler">The Button Click Event</param>
/// <returns>AgDataGridColumn</returns>
public AgDataGridColumn CustomColumn(string headerContent, string control, RoutedEventHandler routedEventHandler)
{
AgDataGridColumn _AgDataGridColumn = new AgDataGridColumn();
_AgDataGridColumn.HeaderContent = headerContent;
_AgDataGridColumn.CellDisplayTemplate = XamlReader.Load(control) as DataTemplate;
_AgDataGridColumn.AllowSorting = DefaultBoolean.False;
_AgDataGridColumn.PrepareCellDisplayElement += (d, _e) =>
{
    ((Button)_e.DisplayElement).Click -= routedEventHandler;
    ((Button)_e.DisplayElement).Click += routedEventHandler;
};
return (_AgDataGridColumn);
}
```

I would like to convert this method to the silverlight datagrid. I am trying to find a proper way of doing the PrepareCellDisplayElement line, adding the event handlers. That method does not seem to exist for sl datagrid. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be found @ http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/189927/440746.aspx. Unfortunately, I do not like the idea of attaching the click event handler on every single data row load.